# language check tool in chaquopy

Tags: python, android, chaquopy, languagetool

I am using this file to check the grammar of the document in an Android application but it gives me error message in the language tool. I am using  `tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')` tool to check the grammar. The error message image in given below

```
import language_check
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
matches=list()
def  main(location):
   # matches.clear()
    mistake=0
    path=location
    uploaded_sentence=open(path).read()
    #uploaded_sentence=path
    tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')
    sent_text = sent_tokenize(uploaded_sentence)
    for sent in sent_text:
        #first letter of the sentence is capital
        doc=sent.capitalize()

        matches=(tool.check(doc))
#        print(len(matches))
        print(sent ,"\n"," mistakes that are in this sentence = ",len(matches),'\n')
        print("type of the mistake that is done","\n ",matches,'\n')

# one of the method for the count grammar mistakes here
# if the mistakes are more than one or one it add only 1 
#        if len(matches)!=0:
#            mistake=mistake+1                      

# the other method for the grammar mistake count
# here if the mistakes are more than one or one it will add the number of the mistakes         
        if (len(matches))>0:
            mistake=mistake+(len(matches))        
    
    print("total number of the mistakes that are done =",mistake)
    return(mistake)
```

[image: Language tool error]

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/397:

> language_check works by running the LanguageTool JAR in a separate Java process and communicating with it over a pipe. Unfortunately Android devices don't come with a Java executable or any other way of executing a JAR, so there's no way language_check can work on Android without significant changes.
>
> An alternative solution might be to download the LanguageTool JAR to your project's libs directory, so it'll be compiled into your app along with the rest of your Java code. Then you can call it directly from Java, or from Python using the [Chaquopy Python API](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html).
>
> See the [language_check source code](https://github.com/myint/language-check) and the [LanguageTool documentation](https://www.languagetool.org/dev) for more details.